# enqueue style sheet to front page on wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to use a separate style sheet to style the front page on a wordpress site. I have tried quite a few things and none of them have worked. here is my current code.

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_style', 'my_portfolio_styles' );
```

if (is_front_page()){
    wp_enqueue_style('front-page',  get_stylesheet_directory().'resources/front-page.css');

```
function my_portfolio_styles(){

    wp_enqueue_style('resources', get_stylesheet_directory_url('front- 
    page.css'),array('front-page.css'));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_enqueue_style()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) is a function, not an action. You have to use [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook and add `wp_enqueue_style()` in it.

You also have to add a **forward slash** `/` after [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/)`. '` because that function is not adding it.

The third argument of `wp_enqueue_style()` is for the dependencies, the fourth is for the stylesheet version number, and the fifth is for the media where you want the stylesheet to be displayed.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_portfolio_styles' );
function my_portfolio_styles(){
  if( is_front_page() ){
     wp_enqueue_style( 'front-page', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/resources/front-page.css', array(), false, 'screen' );
  }
}
```